# C# .NET email client alternate tr row colors based on even / odd

Tags: c#, html, css

Trying to get the  color to alternate colors based on even / odd in c# using inline css

```
 sb.AppendLine("<table width='100%' border='0' align='center' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' style='font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;'><tbody><tr><td style='padding:5px;background-color:rgb(169, 169, 169);color:white;'>Filenames</td></tr>");
 foreach (var item in logList)
 {
    sb.AppendLine("<tr><td style='background-color:#55bada;'>" + Path.GetFileName(item) + "</td></tr>");
    sb.Append("</tr></tbody></table>");
 }
```

I have tried the following but it seems to duplicate the data and not shift the coloring evenly

```
sb.AppendLine("<table width='100%' border='0' align='center' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' style='font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;'><tbody><tr><td style='padding:5px;background-color:rgb(169, 169, 169);color:white;'>Filenames</td></tr>");
int count = 0;
foreach (var item in logList)
{
   for (count = 0; count <= logList.Count; count ++)
   {
      if (count % 2 == 0)
      {
        count += 1;
        sb.AppendLine("<tr><td style='background-color:#bada55;'>" + Path.GetFileName(item) + "</td></tr>");

      }
      else
      {
         count -= 1;
         sb.AppendLine("<tr><td style='background-color:#55bada;'>" + Path.GetFileName(item) + "</td></tr>");
      }
   }
}
sb.Append("</tr></tbody></table>");
```

[Check Even Odd](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-number-is-odd-or-even)
[image: Wrong]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing an extra loop for no reason. Iterate your items once and increase your counter once per item.

```
int count = 0;
foreach (var item in logList)
{
      if (count % 2 == 0)
      {
        sb.AppendLine("<tr><td style='background-color:#bada55;'>" + Path.GetFileName(item) + "</td></tr>");

      }
      else
      {
         sb.AppendLine("<tr><td style='background-color:#55bada;'>" + Path.GetFileName(item) + "</td></tr>");
      }
      count++;
}
```

Comment: something so simple thanks is working as it should be now will accept soon as I can

Answer (score 1):

Have considered something simpler using CSS like:

```
<style>
tr {
    color: blue;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    color: green;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    color: red;
}
 </style>
```

Comment: Many email clients have crappy CSS support.

Comment: what's difference between inline css with style attribute, isn't it all css at the end?

Comment: @Dalorzo I had it setup in css with style at first but as David Corwell stated it wasn't displaying in Outlook they way I wanted so I moved to inline styles

Comment: Depends on the email client.  I wrote an mass emailer that had to target Lotus Notes (years ago).  I couldn't use any CSS at all.

Comment: If you targets emails are on this list then you could use this options it is well supported these days by several email clients: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/